# How to convert a Latex into formulas in Mathematica notebook, the environment is in text, not in input

Tags: latex, wolfram-mathematica

I paste a latex format equations into notebook, but it can't transform into a equation.

Answer (score 0):

Note, backslashes in a text string need to be elided (escaped) with a prior backslash.

```
equation = "\\[ x^n + y^n = z^n \\]";

NotebookWrite[SelectedNotebook[], ImportString[equation, "LaTeX"]]
```

The output is in 'traditional form'.  To convert to Mathematica 'input form' select and Copy As > Plain Text, and paste into a new cell.